# What is the exact function of mix-mainfest.json in Laravel Mix? ( Laravel 5.5 )

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-5.5

I remove my `mix-mainfest.json` and my assets are normally generated by **Laravel Mix** and everything works fine.

In current Laravel documentation (5.5), `mainfest` is not even quoted in Mix session.

Is it still necessary? What is his specific function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for versioning/cache-busting.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/versioning.md